# ColorPickerExtender accessible (keyboard only)

Tags: ajax, accessibility, color-picker, color-palette

I am using the ColorPickerExtender from the Ajax Toolkit.  Just wondering if anyone has had any luck getting this control to be keyboard accessible.  I can get focus on the textbox which brings up the color palette, but I cant select the actual color via keyboard.

If anyone has figured out a work around for this your solution would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering, the most recent version of the ColorPickerExtender is actually keyboard accessible!  If you notice, you can pick the colours from a drop down list of #RRGGBB instead of a color pallet!